# Mysql INSERT WHERE not exists statement inserts two rows, when it should only insert one

Tags: mysql

The following query inserts two rows instead of 1.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (not_primary_id, week_starting, commission)
SELECT '$not_primary_id', '$date', '$amount' 
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  FROM table1
                  WHERE not_primary = '$not_primary_id' 
                   AND week_starting = '$date')
```

When I add

```
LIMIT 1
```

at the end it skips a row id.

What's the right way to do this where I don't skip row id's

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Could you explain a bit more perhaps with some sample data.

Comment: The original had the actual data being given to mysql. In reality that information was given through variables. Does this help you have any idea why the insert would give two?

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Comment: I only added the variable syntax because people mistook it as hard coded constants. In my specific case there aren't any user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

When you are hardcoding the values in the first select, then why don't you directly insert it, and design the table such a way that it don't allow any redundant data. i.e. directly use

```
INSERT INTO table1 (not_primary_id, week_starting, commission)
VALUES ('not_primary_id', '2014-12-08', '0.6');
```

And provide the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for the particular columns which you don't want to hold the same values.